How to create a voltage regulator that creates a constant voltage across a 10 ohms load
I created a simple voltage regulator with a L7905CV and a voltage divider at the output(image below). The regulator is supposed to output 3 volts and it works just fine when I measure the output as an open circuit; however, when I place a load across the output, lets say a 10 ohms resistor, the voltage drops significantly. My objective is to have the voltage regulator output 3 volts across a 10 ohms resistor. Any insight?
Update: I corrected the issue by simply removing the voltage divider. Thanks a lot 1


Post schematic. It looks like you have put a voltage divider on the output of a linear regulator. If you load the bottom resistor of the voltage divider with 10 ohm, of course you won't get the same voltage across that resistor anymore.

L7905CV? You sure about that? L79 is a series of negative voltage regulators

measure the voltage at the top of R1

You need to understand some theory.  https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem  Then look at the LM317 unless you meant -3V reg.

This question is similar to: When would I use a voltage regulator vs a voltage divider?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If the load has a constant 10 Ω resistance, you can reduce the 5 V voltage to 3 V using just one 6.67 Ω resistor in series. The resistor and the load form a voltage divider with a "gain" of 0.6.

You are missing something in your understanding. By adding a series resistor in the output you have destroyed the regulation.
The regulator's action is to maintain a constant voltage at its output terminal (up to its maximum current rating). Its output impedance (resistance) is very close to zero when working within its ratings.
If you require a constant 3 V output then you need a 3 V regulator.

A voltage divider is not a voltage regulator. As you experienced, a voltage divider keeps the voltage only constant if there is no load (or a constant load) current.
If you need a constant 3V independent of the load then you must use a 3V regulator, not a 5V regulator followed by a voltage divider.

If you have a negative voltage source, you can try this circuit..

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
RL = 10 -> 100 Ω


… and its buffered version.

simulate this circuit
RL = 1 -> 100 Ω


The voltmeter with a 10 Ω internal resistance also acts as a load; hence the name "RL=10Ω".

A voltage divider is not a regulator as it had non-zero output impedance. As soon as you put a load and draw current from it, the output voltage drops.
You could buffer the output with a transistor.
If you know the load is a fixed 10 ohm resistor and you need 3V over it, you can calculate the current with Ohm's law and then use Ohm's law again to calculate what resistor value you need to drop 5V to 3V with that current.

What you said is true, but in the title of the question, the OP said, "variable load."

@SolomonSlow OP also said the objective is to have 3V over a 10 ohm load.
